# how to show jscrollPane only when div hovered

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am trying to show jscrollpane visibility only when div is hovered but its not working

here is code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#scroll").on("mouseenter", function(){
              $(this).jScrollPane();
        });

        $("#scroll").on("mouseleave", function(){
             var element = $(this).jScrollPane({});
             var api = element.data('jsp');
             api.destroy();
        });
 });



<td width="200">
        <div id="scroll" style="height:100px;overflow: auto;width: 100%;">
          <p>text -1</p>
          <p>text -2</p>
          <p>text -3</p>
          <p>text -N</p>
        </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you not just init the scrollpane and hide that, and when hovering show the scrollbar.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: i have one table in that i am showing arrayList data from using jsp in  one of cell. As arrayList is having 50,60 elements i want to show jscrollpane thumb visible only when mouse enter that <td> cell

Comment: @Sumit I probably did n't quite get that see if my answer helps...

Comment: how can i show jscrollPane thumb visible only when mouse hover on it ?  for example http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollbarVisibility/

Comment: @Sumit Did you check my demo. That is how it does in my demo.

Comment: ohh sorry i didn't seen updated demo...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you destory scroll pane. It replaces your original div with the original content see the snippet, so the event registered no longer works. You can try using event delegation.

Snippet from JScroll Pane, destroy method:

```
        function destroy(){
            var currentY = contentPositionY(),
                currentX = contentPositionX();
            elem.removeClass('jspScrollable').unbind('.jsp');
            //See the below line
            elem.replaceWith(originalElement.append(pane.children()));
            originalElement.scrollTop(currentY);
            originalElement.scrollLeft(currentX);

            // clear reinitialize timer if active
            if (reinitialiseInterval) {
                clearInterval(reinitialiseInterval);
            }
        }
```

And you don't need to reinitialize it again to destor instead just access the `data('jsp')` directly and invoke destroy on that.

```
    $('table').on("mouseleave","#scroll", function(){ //Attach the event to the closest possible parent
       $(this).data('jsp').destroy();
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ggmz/)**